# How to distribute socket.io servers globally?

Tags: networking, mongodb, websocket, socket.io

We have a Socket.io service that needs constant communication with Mongodb. We currently have a load balancer server, 16 containers in a server (due to nodejs being single threaded, we split processes by dockers so we can utilize entire server) and a MongoDB server.

We aren't in production yet so we didn't create a replication system. But we have a problem.

Our servers are located in Europe. When I measure the latency between South America (We have lots of clients over there) and Europe, it measures around 200 ms. That might be a problem for us. If we create a socket server in South America, then our socket server and database server will have latency issues.

Any idea on how to distribute them globally?

Comment: Will your application actually *have* latency issues, or is that an assumption?

Comment: it's an assumption. @ceejayoz

Comment: You should verify that assumption first, then. This adds an enormous amount of complexity to your application, and there's a very good chance your app will work fine with the latency. Consider instead "optimistic updates" - have your app reflect the update immediately, and roll it back only if the failure comes back in ~200ms.